# is there a simple way to find out if some particular site/web application uses HTML5/CCS3?

Tags: html, css

I've been asked by a recruiter for how many years I'm testing HTML5/CCS3, and I never thought if our app uses any of those, and our UI developer is not online at the moment to ask. I googled it and found on yahoo answers that the source code for the HTML5 page will have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

in it at the top. Is that the only thing to be sure it's HTML5?

What about css3? What should I look for in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### HTML5

HTML5 isn’t one big thing (see http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/introduction.html). There’s no easy way to tell if a given HTML page contains any HTML5 features other than listing all the new features in HTML5, and checking the page for them.

- [Differences between HTML5 and HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/)

The HTML5 doctype is a decent signal that the author intended the page as HTML5, but you can use it on HTML4 pages just as correctly, so it’s not really indicative in and of itself.

#### CSS3

CSS3 is even less one big thing, as CSS has been split into lots of individual modules which are expected to progress individually.

The modules are all listed on the following page. Selectors and CSS Color are considered finished; all the other modules are listed under the **High Priority** and **Medium Priority** headings. Unfortunately I don’t think each module lists which features were added after CSS 2.1, so you’d have to compare them to the 2.1 spec.

- http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

You can pretty much consider HTML and CSS as unversioned languages at this point. I’m sure that won’t stop recruiters asking for *min 5 years HMTL-5 experience* though.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. :) Yeah, they might ask for 5 years of experience with iPad testing. :) Not even sure Mr. Jobs has that much. :)

Answer (score 0):

just download the css files with wget/curl and look at the defs, as well as looking at the page source to see if you see any css3 transforms.  Or use webkit/firebug to look at the css.